# How to troubleshoot Sidebar not being generated

Tags: sidebar, register-sidebar

I'm building a custom theme.  My sidebar is not being generated at all.

In functions.php, I have:

```
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') ) {
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'Standard Sidebar',
        'id' => 'sidebar-1',
        'description' => 'Appears as the sidebar on standard pages',
        'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</li>',
        'before_title' => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
        'after_title' => '</h2>',
    ));
}
```

In sidebar.php, I have:

```
<?php echo '<div>You made it into the sidebar function</div>'; ?>
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) ) : ?>
    <div id="sidebar" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ); ?>
    </div><!-- #sidebar -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

In page.php, I have:

```
<?php
/**
 * Page
 */

get_header();

?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<div class="breadcrumbs_container">
    <div class="breadcrumbs">
        <?php if ( function_exists('yoast_breadcrumb') ) {
            yoast_breadcrumb('<p id="breadcrumbs">','</p>');
        } ?>
    </div>
<div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="content_container">
        <div class="page">
            <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            <div class="content">
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php get_sidebar; ?>
    </div>
</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I don't see "You made it into the sidebar function", and nothing appears in the source code of the page I am displaying.

It is a normal Wordpress page, and I have no custom templates created yet, so it should be using page.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your get_sidebar call:

```
<?php get_sidebar; ?>
```

is missing the parentheses:

```
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
```